# Extra space character is added when reporting a bug via the app itself

Tags: bug, android-app

When adding a bug report via Android app, list of specification items added to message body automatically. And for the last one (OS) extra space character is added.

Comment: No, we can't see the bug in this post, you removed the extra space when you reported it. (Thus wasting time of users trying to figure this out.)